# MVC 4 Razor Engine HttpPostedFileBase not working with Create a strongly-typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my MVC 4 project, I created a view with using "Create a strongly-typed view" as "Scaffold template: Edit". But in that page I try to upload image with file upload methods but in Controller side HttpPostedFileBase is always show null when I run the project.

Here is my Controller:

```
    public ActionResult EditUser(int id)
    {
        if (Session["UserId"] != null)
        {
            return View(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id));
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditUser(User user, HttpPostedFileBase ProfileImage)
    {
        db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

        if (ProfileImage != null && ProfileImage.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/user"), Path.GetFileName(ProfileImage.FileName));
            ProfileImage.SaveAs(filePath);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Profile");
    }
```

Here is my View:

```
@model emirhanozkan.Models.User

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit User";
}

<h2>EditUser</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>@ViewBag.Title</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileImage)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProfileImage, new { type = "file", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileImage)

    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

In input file system get name as ProfileImage.

Here is my Model:

```
namespace emirhanozkan.Models
{
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen bir kullanıcı adı belirleyiniz.")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen email adresinizi giriniz.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3]\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Lütfen geçerli bir email adresi giriniz.")]﻿
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
}
}
```

The `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProfileImage, new { type = "file", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })` is my concoction, I don't know is there any method like that but i tried to use `@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){<input type="file" />}` instead of my code but it didn't work as well.

Do you have any idea about how can i use HttpPostedFileBase in "Create a strongly-typed view" on MVC 4?

Comment: In addition to setting `enctype` in the `<form>` your property should be `HttpPostedFileBase` not `string` and it will be bound to your model  (the 2nd parameter in your POST method is not required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the enctype multipart in beginform something like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go for the **Html.BeginForm** for Sending "**multipart/form-data**" basically you need to mention it whenever you are sending file to controller :

This code will work for you :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditUser", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
     {

     }
```

**Cheers !!**

Comment: The controller and action names are not required. OP's use of `null` is fine.